# What is the most efficient way of drawing a grid with Pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Is there a significant difference in term of performance drawing one rectangle for every cell of the grid compared to drawing the grid using horizontal and vertical lines ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using lines drawing is one or more order of magnitude faster than drawing rectangles. The code below times both methods.

```
import pygame

import os
import time

TITLE = "Draw grid"
WINDOWS_LOCATION = '100,100'
WIDTH = 710
HEIGHT = 710
FPS = 1

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

CELL_SIZE = 15
GRID_COORD_MARGIN_SIZE = 20

class Grid():
    def __init__(self, surface, cellSize, axisLabels):
        self.surface = surface
        self.colNb = surface.get_width() // cellSize
        self.lineNb = surface.get_height() // cellSize
        self.cellSize = cellSize
        self.axisLabels = axisLabels
        self.grid = [[0 for i in range(self.colNb)] for j in range(self.lineNb)]
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 12, False)

    def drawUseRect(self):
        for li in range(self.lineNb):
            liCoord = GRID_COORD_MARGIN_SIZE + li * CELL_SIZE
            if self.axisLabels:
                if li < 10:
                    ident = '   '
                else:
                    ident = '  '
                text = self.font.render(ident + str(li), 1, (0, 0, 0))
                self.surface.blit(text, (0, liCoord))
            for co in range(self.colNb):
                colCoord = GRID_COORD_MARGIN_SIZE + co * CELL_SIZE
                if self.axisLabels:
                    if co < 10:
                        ident = '  '
                    else:
                        ident = ' '
                    text = self.font.render(ident + str(co), 1, (0, 0, 0))
                    self.surface.blit(text, (colCoord, 1))
                pygame.draw.rect(self.surface, BLACK, pygame.Rect(liCoord, colCoord, CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE), 1)

    def drawUseLine(self):
        for li in range(self.lineNb):
            liCoord = GRID_COORD_MARGIN_SIZE + li * CELL_SIZE
            if self.axisLabels:
                if li < 10:
                    ident = '   '
                else:
                    ident = '  '
                text = self.font.render(ident + str(li), 1, (0, 0, 0))
                self.surface.blit(text, (0, liCoord))
            pygame.draw.line(self.surface, BLACK, (GRID_COORD_MARGIN_SIZE, liCoord), (self.surface.get_width(), liCoord))
        for co in range(self.colNb):
            colCoord = GRID_COORD_MARGIN_SIZE + co * CELL_SIZE
            if self.axisLabels:
                if co < 10:
                    ident = '  '
                else:
                    ident = ' '
                text = self.font.render(ident + str(co), 1, (0, 0, 0))
                self.surface.blit(text, (colCoord, 1))
            pygame.draw.line(self.surface, BLACK, (colCoord, GRID_COORD_MARGIN_SIZE), (colCoord,self.surface.get_height()))

# setting Pygame window position (ok on Windows ...)
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = WINDOWS_LOCATION

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption(TITLE)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
axisLabels = False

grid = Grid(surface=screen, cellSize=CELL_SIZE, axisLabels=axisLabels)

while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill(WHITE)

    start = time.time()
    grid.drawUseRect()
    print("draw using rect: {}".format(time.time() - start))

    start = time.time()
    grid.drawUseLine()
    print("draw using line: {}".format(time.time() - start))

    # *after* drawing everything, flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Here's a example of the timing output on a Windows 10 tablet pc:

```
draw using rect: 0.04449152946472168
draw using line: 0.0008492469787597656
draw using rect: 0.012907981872558594
draw using line: 0.0
draw using rect: 0.027329683303833008
draw using line: 0.002046346664428711
draw using rect: 0.019585847854614258
draw using line: 0.0009150505065917969
draw using rect: 0.022649049758911133
draw using line: 0.0009458065032958984
draw using rect: 0.022264480590820312
draw using line: 0.0017306804656982422
draw using rect: 0.022340059280395508
draw using line: 0.0009708404541015625
draw using rect: 0.04112124443054199
draw using line: 0.0019001960754394531
```

And here's a comparison of the visual result of drawing the grid (variable axisLabel set to True):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```py
def draw_grid(surface, rows, cols):
    cell_width = screen_width // cols
    cell_height = screen_height // rows

    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(cols):
            x = col * cell_width
            y = row * cell_height
 
            pygame.draw.rect(surface, color, (x, y, cell_width, cell_height), 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**